# Failed to start BIND : Unknown error

Tags: bind

I am using Debian Linux 5.0 with Webmin and Virtualmin. Everything works fine except the BIND DNS Server. It says

> Failed to start BIND : Unknown error.

Any ideas? I've googled about this problem and found some answers, but didn't help me. I still couldn't start it.

Thanks in advance for any help!
Gabe

Answer (score 1):

Increase the logging level, put this on named.conf:

```
 logging {severity debug;};
```

More info about logging directive:

http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/logging.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Should I check the logs after I put this code in named.conf?

Comment: After you added the line to your `named.conf` and restarted `named`.

Comment: Gabriel: yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

This error is not coming from BIND, but from the startup script or wrapper.

Try running BIND manually, from a root prompt, with:

```
named -g -c /dev/null
```

If this starts, it means BIND is installed and working properly.  The next step is to find out what configuration file it may be using.  You can try leaving off the `-c /dev/null` part and seeing what happens.  If it starts, there is a config file somewhere that it found and loaded.

If no file is found, use the `-c` option and point it at your `named.conf` file specifically.

If those steps all work, then I would check the path that your wrapper script tries to run to ensure that it has the correct one for named.